# Parquet schema evolution strategies

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, hive, apache-spark-sql, parquet

We have a nested (at multiple levels) json as parquet schema. The schema is used to read parquet from S3 using an external table in Hive.

Now the schema has evolved:

1. we have removed and added some columns.
2. Changed meaning of some columns (Example -> Kg to pounds)

The updates are done at attributes which are deeply nested in the schema tree.

What are the options that we have to support this evolution ?

1. Migrate all existing parquet to new schema (read old data, apply new schema, write it back to a new place, update the hive table definition)
2. Use Hive views to handle the schema change.
3. Or any other option which scales as the schema will keep on evolving.

Adding / Removing new columns is kind of easy, and can be done by just updating the hive table definition.

We have tried the approach #1 (migrating the data) for a subset of data and calculated the cost for complete migration. We are looking for ways to see if we can avoid that cost, as our one day worth of data is around 100 GBs and we have data for 3-4 years.

Creating Hive views seems complicated because we have to simulate the nesting of the schema in the view as well to avoid flattening of data.

An example of schema could be:

```
A
|
|-> B
|  |
|  |-> C
|  |-> D
|  |   |-> E          (Say this is changed from KG to POUND)
|  |   |-> F          
|  |   |-> G          (Removed)
|  |   |-> H          (Added)
|  |   |   |-> H1
|  |   |   |-> H2
|  |
|  |-> I
|  |   |-> J
|  |   |-> K
|
|-> L
```